# Pass Arguments to EXE

Tags: vb.net, process

I have a button with this code

```
Process.Start("start system\now.exe")
```

Now I'd like to pass arguments from the Texbox but I dont know how . I've tried :

```
Process.Start("system\now.exe -connect -ip 127.0.0.1 -PORT 910 " & "-USER " & TextBox1.Text & "-PWD " & TextBox1.Text " -serial x4r7680")
```

But does not seem to work. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in a ProcessStartInfo object with the arguments. See the page in the MSDN docs for info on the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class.

Based on a cursory reading of the document, your example would look like this:

```
Dim startInfo as ProcessStartInfo("system\now.exe")
startInfo.Arguments = "-connect -ip 127.0.0.1 -PORT 910 " & "-USER " & TextBox1.Text & "-PWD " & TextBox1.Text " -serial x4r7680"
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Comment: Does not work,if I put the whole command(as an example) it's work , but if I try to read them from the text box does not work

Comment: You may want to compile the argument string using a stringbuilder before passing it into StartInfo.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class. An example:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe")
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized

Process.Start(startInfo)

startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com"

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

but you may also be able to use another [overload of the Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method to pass your command line arguments. Again an example:

```
' Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.htm")
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.asp")
```

or in your case:

```
Process.Start("system\now.exe","-connect -ip 127.0.0.1 -PORT 910 " & "-USER " & TextBox1.Text & "-PWD " & TextBox1.Text " -serial x4r7680")
```

or

Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("system\now.exe")

```
Process.Start(startInfo)

startInfo.Arguments = "-connect -ip 127.0.0.1 -PORT 910 " & "-USER " & TextBox1.Text & "-PWD " & TextBox1.Text " -serial x4r7680"

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

you need to be careful if `TextBox1.Text` contains a space as (depending on how your program parses the command line options) you might end up parsing them incorrectly unless you surround them in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Im sure the problem you have are the quotes "" of the parameters.
This example is using argument parameters.

Try with this:

```
Process.Start("system\now.exe", """" & "-connect -ip 127.0.0.1 -PORT 910 " & "-USER " & lblSubirLlamadasTimeInterval.Text & "-PWD " & lblSubirLlamadasTimeInterval.Text & "-serial x4r7680""")
```